# How can I figure out exactly which process is keeping my Mac from going to sleep and waking it up?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, sleep, wake-up

I have read [this knowledgebase article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776?viewlocale=en_US), but would like to know if there's a way to tell exactly which process is causing my Mac not to follow the sleep schedule I have set in System Preferences > Energy Saver. I have narrowed it down to a being a process and will explain why I think so (see below).

I am running OS X (10.6.5) on the new iMac 27" and I am certain it's not the following:

1. The "Wake for Network Access" checkbox in Energy Saver settings (has never been a previous issue)
2. Peripherals (has never been a previous issue)
3. Any active GUI application (all are closed)
4. Additional USB/FireWire drives (none are connected)
5. Bluetooth (it's off)
6. Sharing services (has never been a previous issue)

The symptoms are as follows:

1. The computer doesn't go to sleep at the predetermined time.
2. It will wake up some number of hours after being put manually to sleep (but not within the first few seconds/minutes.)

Is there a specific string I should be looking for in Console? I have tried searching for "wake" and "sleep" but can't make total sense of the results.

Comment: Remove all *Login Items* from your user account in *System Preferences » Accounts*, log out, and back in. Check all `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDemons` to see if some are third party (probably those *not* `com.apple...`), and disable them for `launchd`. Did you completely replace your previous machine, or do you use both (e.g. same network)?

Comment: @Daniel, please convert your comment to an answer.

Comment: Please follow up on comments and answers for troubleshooting questions such as this. If the problem went away, or you figured it out yourself, please say so.

Comment: Hey Daniel. I'm still sorting it out. I have done what you recommended and it doesn't seem effective either way. Sorry for the delayed feedback.

Comment: I have also noticed that my iMac will wake up every hour on the minute to update network settings (airport). I am viewing this in the console. Additionally,in viewing console output, I see this string as frequently as every two minutes, to as sparse as every 1.5 or 2 hours.

2010/12/30 19:00:41 kernel AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was that iMac was physically located at just the right place (or wrong place) to cause it to switch back and forth between two wireless access points. This apparently was resetting the sleep timer.

Answer (score 0):

- Remove all *Login Items* from your user account in *System Preferences » Accounts*, log out, and back in.
- Check all `LaunchAgents` and `LaunchDemons` to see if some are third party (probably those not `com.apple...`), and disable them for `launchd`.

If the issue disappears, it's based on some software you're running in the background.

Did you completely replace your previous machine, or do you use both (e.g. same network)?

<sup>While I don't see the value in "guessing" answers for troubleshooting issues, I'm posting this as an answer as per @Randolph Potter's request</sup>

Comment: I removed all login items and LaunchDaemons and LaunchAgents that were third-party (even though they didn't cause problems before). Still no change. This is not a new machine or a restore. This is just a recently-occurring problem.